# Does the Linux implementation of quicksort "back off" to insertion sort?

Tags: linux, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

I was reading in Bentley & McIlroy (1993) that their suggested implementation of Quicksort uses Insertion Sort when the arrays get small enough.

I was curious to know whether modern-day kernels use this same maneuver. Does anyone know whether the Linux kernel, for instance, switches from Quicksort to Insertion Sort in this way?

Comment: Is there a quick sort in the kernel?  Or do you mean qsort in gcc or the GNU command line sort program?

Comment: If you're asking about the `qsort()` function in the standard C library (*not* the kernel), though the name was probably derived from "Quicksort", there's no requirement in the standard about how it's implemented. (That doesn't answer your question, which is why this is a comment.)

Comment: That's interesting to know about the C library that ships with Linux. I'd be further interested to know whether the OS itself has some potentially other subroutine for sorting defined for its own purposes.... Maybe it doesn't, but I'd be curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the qsort from the C library, here's the `qsort()` from a somewhat recent glibc, which is the one used in most Linux systems: http://www.cs.umaine.edu/~chaw/200801/capstone/n/qsort.c.html.

It does indeed switch to insertion for small partitions.  It happens to use 4 elements for the threshold, though it's possible the empirically-selected number needs updating.

```
/* Discontinue quicksort algorithm when partition gets below this size.
   This particular magic number was chosen to work best on a Sun 4/260. */
#define MAX_THRESH 4
```

Comment: "chosen to work best on a Sun 4/260"? I definitely agree it needs updating.

Comment: Yeah, that was supposed to be sarcasm ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the qsort from the Linux standard C library (GLIBC), that's actually implemented as merge sort, not quick sort. It will only fall back to an in-place quick sort if it's unable to allocate enough memory for merge sort.

Don't believe me? Check out the source code for `qsort()` in GLIBC here: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/msort.c;hb=HEAD#l306

Mats Linander has a great article summarizing the various implementations for `qsort()` in different standard C libraries here: http://calmerthanyouare.org/2013/05/31/qsort-shootout.html (hint: most don't actually use quick sort!)