# Insertion Sort is a good choice for "small" data sets. What is "small"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

There are many places I have seen where it talks about how Insertion Sort is good for small data sets.  I can't find a number for what "small" is though.  My guess is that there is no absolute answer and that it depends on the type of machine the code is being run on.

However, what factors go into deciding what is the threshold for when Insertion Sort is a good idea?  And what are some ballpark figures for "small"? 5?  10? 50? 100?

Thanks!

Site saying Insertion Sort is good for small data sets:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/insertion-sort

Comment: What is your definition of "a small sum of money"? Small means small enough in *your* circumstances. *You* should test on *your* hardware with *your* data and find the threshoold size that works for *you*. Having said that, GNU qsort implementation defines it to be 4, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123683/does-the-linux-implementation-of-quicksort-back-off-to-insertion-sort

Comment: Thank you.  That is significantly smaller than what I always assumed, which was ~30.

Comment: I always assumed something around 30 too, I think I've seen it in some qsort implementation, but then I googled it for the comment above and found 4...

Comment: Microsoft template library (algorithm) uses 32 for both std::sort and std::stable_sort.

Comment: @n.m. but that code is only used if the dataset is "too big" to do a mergesort (which requires a memory allocation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right - there is no absolute answer, one have to measure where is threshold between insertion sort and other methods.

For example, typical values for triggering to insertion sort (and get some gain, of course) for small pieces inside combined merge or quick sort are about 32-100 (but can vary depending on data and implementation details)

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at an answer, providing we're talking about the general sorting problem. Insertion sort is on average O(n^2), efficient sorting algorithms are on average O(nlogn). So vaguely speaking if something takes K steps to sort efficiently it will take around (kind of) K^2 steps with insertion sort.

So if n > K is too slow for your liking with an efficient sort, n > K^0.5 will be too slow for you (roughly) with insertion sort.

Practically speaking let's say you're happy to sort arrays of size 10^8 with something efficient then you might be happy to sort arrays of size 10^4 with insertion sort.